# does s.e.s 0->A->B->C->0 of profinite groups imply C=B/A and A<B topologically?

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups, short-exact-sequences

Assume $A, B, C$ are profinite groups and $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is an exact sequence of continuous maps. Which of the following assertions follows?:

(i) the subspace-topology induced on $A$ via $A\hookrightarrow B$ agrees with the given one.

(ii) the quotient-topology induced on $C$ via $B\twoheadrightarrow C$ agrees with the given one.

Comment: Both assertions are true, using twice that a continuous bijection between compact spaces is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Yves: You also need that the profinite topology is Hausdorff and the quotient topology on $B/A$ is Hausdorff for your argument to work. I don't quite see how to prove $B/A$ is Hausdorff after thinking for just a minute. 

Comment: @Agol: I was thinking of the French sense of compact which includes Hausdorff (actually compact groups and locally compact groups are even in the English conventions often assumed Hausdorff). Now since $A$ is closed, the unit is closed in $B/A$; while a topological group is Hausdorff iff `$\{1\}$`is closed. 

Comment: See Proposition 2.1 in this paper for Yves claim ($T_1\implies T_2$ for topological groups). 
http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/PadicGroups/topgroups.pdf

Comment: Is this question just asking about profinite spaces, or does it matter that they are groups? Or should the question ask for the continuous maps to be homomorphisms?

Comment: If the topological group $G$ is $T_1$, then $G$ is $T_2$ because the diagonal of $G\times G$ is closed as the inverse image of $(g,h)\mapsto gh^{-1}$.

Comment: Nice Yves. Maybe you should write up a complete answer (I suppose clarifying the Hausdorff issue for Americans). 